# Handling arrays of objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm new to Java and used to create arrays and objects in PHP.

Now I wrote a short function in Java for extractions some parts of the text. The function packs up all extracted text pieces into an object and returns to the main code. However whatever I do with the returned result I can't get items back from that.

Here is my code:

```
public void main(String text) {

    Object[] entities = (Object[])extractNamedEntities(text);

    Object names = entities[0];
    Object locations = entities[1];
    Object orgs = entities[2];

    for (Sting name : names) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}


private static Object extractNamedEntities(String text) {

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> orgs = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Then processing the text and then...

    names.add("Name1");
    names.add("Name2");
    locations.add("Loc1");
    locations.add("Loc2");
    orgs.add("Org1");

    return new Object[]{names, locations, orgs};
}
```

I get the following error:

> Compilation failure for-each not applicable to expression type required: array or java.lang.Iterable found: java.lang.Object

Comment: `names` is just a single `Object` - you cannot iterate it because there is only 1. If you want to handle it as a `List` you need to cast it to a `List`.

Comment: @takendarkk I though it is an ArrayList based on `ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();`, not correct?

Comment: Why not return a list of lists instead of an object?

Comment: You made it a List, but then later you said "forget the list, treat it as an object" when you did this - `Object names = entities[0];` You had to do that because your method is returning an `Object[]` instead of a List of Lists. Basically, why did you do this `return new Object[]{names, locations, orgs};`? Making `Object` is throwing away all the useful stuff about the lists you just made.

Comment: @takendarkk `ArrayList<String> names = entities[0];`?

Comment: No need to ask me, you can just try it and see. That said, it won't work because your method throws away the List info as soon as it returns. `entities[0]` is NOT a `List`, it is an `Object`. You method explicitly turns it into an `Object` before returning for some reason.

Comment: @takendarkk I get `incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>`

Comment: The type of *variable* `Object names = ...` is `Object`. Because compiler doesn't have any guarantee that *value* of that variable will always be some kind of iterable object holding strings (since `Object` type variable can also hold any other type, like Integer, String, Person, etc...) it will not allow us to create code which potentially will try to iterate some non-iterable object since that would break type-safety which is one of main reasons we use Java.

Comment: To give compiler such guarantee you can explicitly use casting to `ArrayList<String>` like `ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>)entities[0];` which will make type of `names` variable `ArrayList<String>`. OR don't declare your `extractNamedEntities` method to return an `Object`. Since it will always return group of ArrayLists of Strings you can declare that it returns something like `List<ArrayList<String>>` and `return Arrays.asList(names, names, locations, orgs);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is a statically-typed language. What that means is that you can only call methods that are defined on the (static) type of your object references.

Take this for example:

```
String s = "hello";
Object o = s;
```

You have two variables `s` and `o`, both holding a reference to a string. You can call `s.length()` and get the string's length. But you *cannot* call `o.length()`, because `o` is typed as `Object` and the Object type does not define the `length()` method.

Define the proper types and you should be fine. Do you see that cast to an Object array when storing the return value of the method? You can get rid of that too if you declare your method to return an Object array directly. Or even better yet, declare it with the actual type that is being returned: `List<String>[]` (or change the code to return a list instead of an array: `List<List<String>>`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

the `public void main(String text)` must be `public static void main(String text[])`
and the methode signature was also wrong change `private static Object extractNamedEntities(String text)` to `extractNamedEntities(String text[])`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String text[]) {

        Object[] entities = (Object[]) extractNamedEntities(text);

        Object names = entities[0];
        Object locations = entities[1];
        Object orgs = entities[2];
        System.out.println(names);
        System.out.println(locations);
        System.out.println(orgs);
    }


    private static Object extractNamedEntities(String text[]) {

        ArrayList < String > names = new ArrayList < String > ();
        ArrayList < String > locations = new ArrayList < String > ();
        ArrayList < String > orgs = new ArrayList < String > ();

        // Then processing the text and then...

        names.add("Name1");
        names.add("Name2");
        locations.add("Loc1");
        locations.add("Loc2");
        orgs.add("Org1");

        return new Object[] {
            names,
            locations,
            orgs
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: No, wait! It is still object and I couldn't iterate through that. But I have managed to keep the structure with `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` and it is working now!